# A Linq to replace unwanted characters

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have a Linq code to get acceptable characters and remove others.
But this code replace others with ""(nothing + null+ string.empty etc)
I would like to replace with space ( ). How can I do it?

Thanks a lot.

```
string clean = new string(incomingText.Where(c => @" 0123456789abcçdefgğhıijklmnöopqrsştuüvwxyz".Contains(c)).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well you could use:

```
// Alternatively use a HashSet<char>
string acceptableCharacters = " 1234...";
string clean = new string(incomingText.Select(c => acceptableCharacters.Contains(c) ?
                                                   c : ' ')
                                      .ToArray());
```

Note that this still really isn't terribly efficient. I'd probably use a call to `Regex.Replace` instead.

```
Regex invalidCharacterPattern = new Regex("[^ 0-9a-zçğıöşü]");
string clean = invalidCharacterPattern.Replace(incomingText, " ");
```

Comment: @p.s.w.g: Um, I hadn't thought of the ranges yet. The OP would need to add in all the accented characters too. Edited that in now.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov: Well partly that, and partly that I'm travelling, I got up at 5.30am and my body currently thinks it's 2am :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Ahhh the joy of writing code on my iPad or my phone ... :) best I can do is comment, not sure how you're posting such answers, I have to practice more I guess :)

Comment: am i told before? i love you :)

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov: Oh I'm on my laptop now - but my fingers are starting to freeze up, as it's *really* cold in Ohio.

Comment: let me understand the thing, regex more faster?

Comment: @ErçinDedeoğlu: I would expect it to be, yes. You should test according to your own performance requirements, of course.

Comment: @JonSkeet just landed in Cleveland and already answered, amazing!

Comment: Between Linq and Regex have 20ms differences on my test. Regex better. Thanks again.

Comment: @GSerjo: Oh I landed over an hour ago now - only 4 answers though :(

Comment: @JonSkeet Ohio ? Are you going to Code Mash ? I love your talks glad you're doing more of them lately, still waiting for the videos from NDC London ... :) This is turning into a chat room, so I'll stop :)